# LINQ to Objects, query arrays in object

Tags: vb.net, arrays, linq

I need to query an array. I have tried to use LINQ but with no success.

Here is a simplified structure of Insurance

```
Public Class Insurance
       Public _typ As String
        Public _numb As Number()
        Public _indi As Indicator()
End Class

Public Class Number
        Sub New(ByVal n As String, ByVal i As String)
            Me._ntype = n
            Me._value = i
        End Sub
        Public _ntype As String
        Public _value As String

End Class

Public Class Indicator
        Sub New(ByVal it As String, ByVal ind As String)
            Me._itype = it
            Me._ind = ind
        End Sub
        Public _itype As String
        Public _ind As String
End Class
```

Here I have construct a little example to explain how the array of Insurance looks. In real there is a Service who delivers the array to me.

```
  Dim insarray(4) As Insurance
  Dim insa As New Insurance
  insa._typ = "SJUKVARD"
  insa._indi = New Indicator() {New Indicator("ST", "G"), New Indicator("TAX", "P"), New Indicator("PT", "6")}
  insa._numb = New Number() {New Number("PIN", "1000"), New Number("AGN", "A0001")}
  insarray(0) = insa

  Dim insa2 As New Insurance
  insa2._typ = "SJUKVARD"
  insa2._indi = New Indicator() {New Indicator("ST", "G"), New Indicator("TAX", "P")}
  insa2._numb = New Number() {New Number("PIN", "2000"), New Number("AGN", "A0002")}
  insarray(1) = insa2

  Dim insa3 As New Insurance
  insa3._typ = "SJUKVARD"
  insa3._indi = New Indicator() {New Indicator("ST", "G"), New Indicator("KAL", "T")}
  insa3._numb = New Number() {New Number("PIN", "3000"), New Number("AGN", "A0003")}
  insarray(2) = insa3

  Dim insa4 As New Insurance
  insa4._typ = "SJUKVARD"
  insa4._indi = New Indicator() {New Indicator("ST", "G"), New Indicator("TAX", "P")}
  insa4._numb = New Number() {New Number("PIN", "4000")}
  insarray(3) = insa4

  Dim insa5 As New Insurance
  insa5._typ = "SJUK"
  insa5._indi = New Indicator() {New Indicator("ST", "F"), New Indicator("TAX", "P")}
  insa5._numb = New Number() {New Number("PIN", "5000"), New Number("AGN", "A0005")}
  insarray(4) = insa5

  Dim myIns As IEnumerable(Of Object)

  myIns = ...(here should to LINQ question be)
```

In "myIns= ..." I want to construct a LINQ query which

- look for Insurances in the array which have _typ="SJUKVARD"
- and in the Insurance _numb array if some of the Number objects has
  _ntype="AGN"
- and in the Insurance _indi array if some of the Indicator objects has
  _itype="TAX"
- and in the Insurance _indi array if some of the Indicator objects has
  _itype="ST" AND _ind="G"
- and in the Insurance _indi array NOT has a Indicator objects with
  _type="PT

So the only hit will be Insurance "insa2". Is this possible with LINQ?

Hope someone can help me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 myIns = insarray.Where(Function(i) i._typ = "SJUKVARD" AndAlso _
          i._numb.Any(Function (n) n._ntype = "AGN") AndAlso _
          i._indi.All(function(ind) (ind._itype <> "PT") AndAlso  _
          (ind._itype = "TAX" OrElse ( ind._itype = "ST" AndAlso ind._ind="G"))))
```